# How to create NHibernate relationship mapping between multiple entities to another entity (i.e inheritance mapping)

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have this relationship between Car, Bike, Skateboard object with a Person object.
The relationship is stored in Ownership table.

[image: Car, Bike, Skateboard map to Person]

How do I create this mapping in NHibernate ? I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will post the .hbm.xml later. Seem that I should use inheritance mapping, but which mapping type is the best: table per concrete class ? Or using implicit polymorphism (see the link above) ?

Comment: I must confess this model seems a little odd to me. I would insert a Vehicle class as superclass of car/bike/sb. This class would be the one holding the typecode logic. Then you could rely on a "table per hierarchy" strategy

Comment: In fact, Car/Bike/Skateboard is just a simple sample. In our real app, the real objects are much different. For e.g: even the Id propery of each class is different - some use Int64, some use GUID...For the sake of asking, I simplified them as Car/Bike/Skateboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I might do it.

```
<class lazy="false"  name="Domain.OwnerShip, Domain" table="OwnerShip_Table">
  <id name="Id" column="OwnerShipId" type="System.Int32" access="property">
    <generator class="identity"></generator>
  </id>
  <joined-subclass name="Car" table="Cars" lazy="false">
    <key column="Id" />
    <property name="Owner" />
  </joined-subclass>
  <joined-subclass name="Bike" table="Bikes" lazy="false">
    <key column="Id" />
    <property name="Owner" />
  </joined-subclass>
  <joined-subclass name="Skateboard" table="Skateboards" lazy="false">
    <key column="Id" />
    <property name="Owner" />
  </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

You would probably want a Persons table as well as a Person Entity with a mapping where Person has a Bag of OwnedVehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option, with a table per hierarchy.
I assume :

- Ownership holds its own Id (`OwnerShipId`, auto-generated)
- you have a column per referenced class/table (`BikeId, CarId`), to handle different key types and foreign keys

The mapping would then look something like :

```
<class lazy="false"  name="Domain.OwnerShip, Domain" table="OwnerShip_Table" discriminator-value="0">
<id name="Id" column="OwnerShipId" type="System.Int32" access="property">
    <generator class="identity"></generator>
</id>
    <discriminator column="VehicleTypeCode" type="int"/>
    <many-to-one name="Owner" column="PersonId" not-null="true" fetch="..."/>
    <many-to-one name="CodeType" column="VehicleTypeCode" not-null="true" fetch="..." />
<subclass name="Domain.BikeOwnerShip, Domain" discriminator-value="1">
        <many-to-one name="Bike" column="BikeId" not-null="true" fetch="..."/>
   </subclass>
<subclass name="Domain.CarOwnerShip, Domain" discriminator-value="2">
        <many-to-one name="Car" column="CarId" not-null="true" fetch="..."/>
   </subclass>
</class>
```

I guess it would also be nice to have a virtual, not mapped, `OwnedObject` property in the base class, something like

```
public virtual Object OwnedObject{ 
                                 get{return null;}
}
```

in the `CarOwnership` class the OwnedObject implementation would be

```
public override Object OwnedObject{ 
                                 get{return this.Car;}
}
```

Hope this will help